# Swagger (OpenAPI) : how to specify example String dynamically generated from a custom Object?

Tags: java, spring, swagger, openapi, springdoc

## Context

Say you have:

```
public class Dto {
  private String name;
  private String List<String> customs;

  // getters and setters...
}
```

and

```
public class Custom {
  private String something;
  private String else;
  
  // getters and setters...
}
```

Your Spring MVC `RestController` receives a list of `Dto`:

```
@PostMapping
public String create(@RequestBody List<Dto> dtos) {
  return myService.process(features);
}
```

## Input

However, you know that the client-side service which will send data to your controller will send something like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Bob",
    "customs": [
      "{\n        \"something\": \"yes\",\n        \"else\": \"no\"\n      }"
    ]
  }
]
```

Notice how **the `String` is a json representation of the `Custom` class**. Please assume this cannot be changed on the client-side and we have to deal with it on the server-side.

## Question

Is there an OpenAPI annotation which would allow me to designate `Custom` as being the object to be automagically converted to a `String` which would then be used as the example in the UI?

By "used as the example", I'm talking about this automatically generated json (please disregard the actual data shown there since it doesn't match the presented simplified problem):

[image: Swagger UI screenshot to better illustrate]

I'm asking for an ***automatic*** set up because I would prefer not having to go back onto the `String`'s specifics if we end up modifying the properties of the `Custom` class (removing the `something` attribute, for example).

We are using those Maven dependencies:

```
    <!-- Swagger / OpenAPI -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: How you are using `springdoc` and `springfox` together?

Comment: @SSK thanks for making me realize that! I removed ``springfox`` in my repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to designate DTO as being the object to be automatically converted to a string representation for the openAPI documentation UI, Swagger openApi provides a set of annotations found in this library:

```
<groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
<artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
<version>...</version>
```

You can make use of them to fix your problem, by using the [`@ApiModel`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Annotations) annotation on your Dto.

By using these annotations all changes to your models are picked up and updated in the documentation automatically

Comment: ``@ApiModel`` is from an older version of Swagger, but it is indeed what I was looking for, so I found the OpenAPI equivalent: ``@ArraySchema``. Thanks!